# Is there a faster way to read, resort and convert a binary file?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, sorting, binary, fft

I have a binary file that contains a certain number of samples and each sample contains four bytes. The data is acquired via 14 bit ADCs and I have the following bit assignment: b31-b29=Not Used, b28=Digital input, b27-b14=chB(signed), b13-b0=chA(signed). In the end I want to perform a FFT for chA and chB. To get there I use the following Python code:

*1. Here the binary data file is opened as a bitstring and the samples, i.e. 516x1024x32x32 bits are read and appended to a bit array. This is done by reading one sample (4 bytes or 32 bits) at a time, inverting the byte order and then putting this bitstring in a bit array. This is repeated for all samples:*

```
swap = BitArray()

f = ConstBitStream(filename='data.kbin')
f.pos = 0
samples = 516*1024*32
sample_rate = 30517.578125

for i in range(samples):
    data = BitArray()
    g = f.read('bits:32')
    data.append(g)
    data.byteswap(4)
    swap.append(data)
```

*2. The newly ordered array is again opened as bitstring:*

```
data2 = ConstBitStream(swap)
```

*3. The bitstring is now read in a way so that the correct bit assignment (as shown above) is applied and each bitstring is converted to a signed integer. Also each integer referring to chA and chB are put into the corresponding list:*

```
chA = []
chB = []

data2.pos = 0
for i in range(samples):
    a = data2.read('int:3')
    b = data2.read('int:1')
    c = data2.read('int:14')
    d = data2.read('int:14')
    chA.append(d)
    chB.append(c)
```

*4. Calculating the FFT:*

```
dt = 1 / sample_rate

yf_A = fftpack.rfft(chA)
yf_B = fftpack.rfft(chB)
xf = fftpack.rfftfreq(samples, dt)
```

This code works and I get the desired result but it takes really long. The first step takes almost 10 min and the third about 3 min. I am quite new to Python so my knowledge is rather small. How can I speed things up?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much faster way:

```
# input the path t the data file
file_kbin = input("Path to data file: ")

# initialize two lists where the converted data for chA and chB will be stored

CHA = []
CHB = []

# get the number of samples in the data file

size = 516 * 1024 * 32

# here the binary file is opened and converted following the byte assignment given above
with open(file_kbin, 'rb') as data:

    data.seek(0)                                          # make sure to start at the beginning of the file

    for i in range(size):                                 # loop over the complete file

        sample = data.read(4)                             # read one sample (byte0 byte1 byte2 byte3) 
        tmp = int.from_bytes(sample, byteorder='little')  # store the data as integer following the byteorder little (byte3 byte2 byte1 byte0)          

        chA = tmp & 0x00003FFF                            # set chA to byte1 byte0 with b15 and b14 = 0
        if (chA & 0x2000):                                # check if chA negative
            chA = chA - 0x4000                            # get the correct negative value

        chB = (tmp & 0x0FFFc000) >> 14                    # set all bits to 0 except for b27-b14 and shift right by 14 bits
        if (chB & 0x2000):                                # check if chB negative
            chB = chB - 0x4000                            # get the correct negative value

        CHA.append(chA)                                   # store the values in the corresponding list
        CHB.append(chB)
```

(Using the corresponding code in C++ would again be a lot faster.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    from functools import partial

    CHA = []
    CHB = []

    def chk_neg(my_ch):
        if my_ch & 0x2000:
            my_ch -= 0x4000
        return my_ch


    def do(file_kbin):
        with open(file_kbin, 'rb') as data:

            for sample in iter(partial(data.read, 4, b""):
                tmp = int.from_bytes(sample, byteorder='little')          

                chA =tmp & 0x00003FFF
                CHA.append( chk_neg(chA))                          
               
                chB = (tmp & 0x0FFFc000) >> 14                        
                CHB.append(chk_neg(chB))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        file_kbin = input("Path to data file: ")
        do(file_kbin)
```